# How to resume the execution of the submit event after an e.preventDefault()?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Good day. I have the following code:

```
$(document).on('submit','#formEdit',function(e){
    if(<?=$id_rol?> != $("#select_privilegios").val()){
      <?php if($id_usuario_actual == $userID):?>
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#warningEditarRol').modal();
        $('#warningEditarRol').modal('open');
        if($("#warningEditarRol .statusBtn").on("click",function(){
          //here resume the execution of the submit event
        }));
      <?php endif;?>      
    }
});
```

This code what it does is that if certain conditions are met, it opens a `modal window` (`#warningEditarRol`) with two buttons, one to cancel and the other to continue (`.statusBtn`). What I want to do is that when I select the continue button, I resume the execution of the submit event, and I sent the form, but I really have no idea how to do it, if someone could guide me on that, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Capture the form data and complete an Ajax request as necessary. https://api.jquery.com/event.data/ http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can't resume an event after a `preventDefault()`.

But you don't have to:

```
// direct submit is prohibited by default
var doSubmit = false;
$(document).on('submit','#formEdit',function(e){
    if(<?=$id_rol?> != $("#select_privilegios").val()){
        <?php if($id_usuario_actual == $userID):?>
            if (doSubmit) {
                // this submit will pass but next one will be promted for
                doSubmit = false;
            } else {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#warningEditarRol').modal();
                $('#warningEditarRol').modal('open');
                if($("#warningEditarRol .statusBtn").on("click",function(){
                    // unlock submit and resubmit
                    doSubmit = true;
                    $('#formEdit').submit();
                }));
            }

        <?php endif;?>      
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to use AJAX and send POST data to a PHP file.

```
$(document).on('submit','#formEdit',function(e){
if(<?=$id_rol?> != $("#select_privilegios").val()){
  <?php if($id_usuario_actual == $userID):?>
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#warningEditarRol').modal();
    $('#warningEditarRol').modal('open');
    if($("#warningEditarRol .statusBtn").on("click",function(){
      //here resume the execution of the submit event using AJAX
      $.post(/*1st Argument:URL or PHP file you want to send data to,2nd 
Argument:Data that you may send,
3rd Argument:Callback function to call upon successful submission of data*/);
    }));
  <?php endif;?>      
   }
});
```

This method involves a little complexity but AJAX can provide many useful features. You can search online for it but providing any more info about it here for me would be off topic.